# Zendesk-GoogleCloud間通信のセキュリティ（暗号化）について

Tags: google-cloud

現在、弊社ではサポートSaaSツールの [Zendesk](https://www.zendesk.co.jp/) を使用中なのですが、このツールに御社のGoogle Cloud翻訳を利用した自動翻訳機能があります。この機能利用による、Zendesk-GoogleCloud間通信のセキュリティについてお伺いいいたします。

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit/?hl=ja
上記ページで

> 転送データの暗号化: データがユーザーのサイトとクラウド プロバイダの間または 2 つのサービスの間を移動する際に傍受された場合、そのデータを保護します。この保護は、送信前のデータ暗号化、各エンドポイントの認証、到着時のデータ解読と検証により実現されます。

とありますが、これは「ZendeskとGoogle Cloud API間の通信についても暗号化が実施されている」という理解でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「御社」という表現を使っていますが一応ここも見ておいたほうがいいかも？[製品やライブラリの公式サイトからこのサイトを訪れた方へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2111/) と[製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: 投稿者です。ご指摘ありがとうございます。以後注意いたします。

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit/?hl=ja に下のように書かれているとおり、このページで解説されているのは Google Cloud 内での通信に関するものであり、Zendesk と Google Cloud 間の通信に関するものではありません。

> このホワイトペーパーでは、Google Cloud Platform や Google Workspace を含む Google Cloud での転送データの暗号化について詳しく説明します。

Zendesk 側はデータ保護について https://www.zendesk.co.jp/company/privacy-and-data-protection/ というドキュメントを出しているので、もしかするとこれで回答に足るかもしれません。

ただしここにも Zendesk と Google Cloud 間の通信について具体的に書かれてはいませんし、また質問者さんのおっしゃる「暗号化」がどういう用途を想定されたものか分からず上記の書かれ方で充分か分からないので、もしより具体的な言質が必要であれば、Zendesk の製品サポートから問い合わせていただくのが良さそうかなと思います: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/ja/。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。たいへん参考になりました。
確実なところはZendeskサポートに確認してみます。
ありがとうございました！